# Java for (;;) loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I was looking at the `AtomicBoolean` class source and found interesting declaration of the `for` loop like this:

```
for (;;) { 
   //Something
}
```

What does this loop?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is an infinite loop. The same you can do with:

```
while (true) {
  //Loops forever.
}
```

Take a look at the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Comment: Because you want your code to be as simple and understandable as possible. `for (;;)` is gibberish. It makes people stop and think about what it does. If your code isn't readable, it becomes difficult for other people (and you, two months after writing it) to understand and bug fix.

Answer (score 2):

This is shorthand for an infinite loop. It will continue until a break statement causes execution to escape the loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is an endless loop that will not stop execution if you have no `break` statement inside. It's the same as `while(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

> What does this loop?

It loops indefinitely. It's like:

```
while (true) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (;;) { 
   //Something
}
```

This is infinite loop.